# How to constantly define and then empty a string in a loop with C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, algorithm, loops

Suppose that I need to write a program in C that takes in a name of an edible plant
and then print if it is a fruit or a vegetable. You know input will be one of three
things; apple, orange, or cabbage.
Here is the pseudocode for how I would do it:

```
while input != quit:  
 read input  
 if input is orange or apple(or some other fruit then print fruit)  
 else  if input is cabbage print vegetable
```

The way I would do it in C is by using a while loop and storing input as 
a string. Then compare input to a define set of elements (fruit set or vegetable set) and output results. Pretty straightforward.

This way input is read and initialized to e.g. string S. 
Then S is compared to the set and accordingly output is given or program quits. 
But this means string S is rewritten with every new iteration. Since we don't know 
the length of input string for the next iteration we need to 'clear' the entire length 
of S so that a new input can be rewritten to it correctly.

But this means for each input string 
of length n, the program has to 'insert' a character into string S n times and when done must 
'clear' a character entered also n times before the next iteration. I am wondering 
if there is a more efficient way to carry out this task.

**P.S.** A full explanation of a possible solution is appreciated. I kindly request refraining
from referencing a function from a standard library(e.g. string.h) or another without
indicating how it works.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Why is it difficult to reset the string? In your desired algorithm, is O(n) with n the length of the string, or the number of words in the set?

Comment: So suggesting you look up `gets()` and `scanf()`, and saying you "clear" a string such as `char mystring[11];` with `mystring[0] = 0;` would be too hard for you?

Comment: maybe it is On^2 if you consider iterating over all inputs and then iterating over all stored strings? thats two for loops for a simple approach. You could use a tree structure stored alphabetically for the set of words, each word represented by a struct containing name and type - then search that tree for each input string? gets you down to Onlogn

Comment: If it is `O(n*n*n)` that would be a cubecumber.

Comment: well only a vegetable would implement an algorithm as fruity as that. w.r.t. my original suggestion fruits definitely grow on trees, not so sure about vegetables

Comment: You don't have to clear the string before reading new data into it.  Functions such as `fgets()` or `scanf()` will overwrite the previous data and null terminate the new input.

Comment: @WeatherVane: never suggest the use of `gets()`.  Never!

Comment: @WeatherVane I agree with @JonathanLeffler. `gets` has actually been removed completely from the 2011 ISO C standard because it is impossible to guarantee that buffer overflows will never result.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler and @Chrono Kitsune - yes thanks, my oversight. I actually use the safe MS Visual C `gets_s()` and for the same reason I don't use `strcpy()` but either `strcpy_s()` or `strncpy()`. I get the point though, with `gets()` you can't check the string length first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one problem where you can really **make it just as difficult as you want to..**  It all depends on your needs. If you have a static set of fruits and vegetables (or stuff), then you can use something as simple as a comma separated `string literal` to hold all values in one category or another. (the comma is just for readability)

If on the other hand, you need to be able to `insert` and `delete` new values to fruits or vegetables, then you will need a datastruct that will allow for easy insertion/deletion and searching. Which datastruct will depended on how many and how often inserts/deletes are done. (any will work, but e.g. a `bst` is less efficient on insert/delete, but more efficient on search -- it's a tradeoff)

However, regardless of how simple or complex your implementation, it all boils down to a reliable way to get input and a reliable test that is flexible enough to handle what the user inputs. The following is just one example of a simple implementation with consideration given to conversion of all input to lowercase, a reasonable input routine and a simple comparison with `strstr` against `string literals`. You can compare with other answers and get a flavor for the different approaches that you can take:

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <string.h>

#define MAXS 255

char *str2lower (char *str);                /* convert string to lowercase */

int main () {

    char line[MAXS] = {0};                  /* array of 255 chars for input set to 0            */
    int match = 0;                          /* var to test scanf result                         */
    char *fruit = "orange,apple,banana";    /* if fruits are known, a simple string is fine     */
    char *veg   = "cabbage,lettuce";        /* same for vegetables                              */
    int cnt = 1;                            /* simple counter                                   */

    while (strcmp (line, "quit") != 0)      /* loop until quit or match failure                 */
    {
        if (cnt == 1)  printf ("\nEnter produce (quit to end): ");
        else           printf ("  next: ");

        match = scanf ("%[^\n]%*c", line);  /* match = 1 on success (1 match) up to 255 chars   */
        if (!match)
            strncpy (line, "quit", strlen ("quit") + 1); /* set quit to exit (could use break;) */

        str2lower(line);                    /* convert input to lower case before test          */

        if (strstr (fruit, line))           /* use simple strstr test to categorize             */
            printf ("                  entry [%2d]  %-10s -> fruit\n", cnt, line);
        else if (strstr (veg, line)) 
            printf ("                  entry [%2d]  %-10s -> vegetable\n", cnt, line);
        else if (strcmp (line, "quit") != 0)
            printf ("                  entry [%2d]  %-10s -> no match\n", cnt, line);

        cnt++;
    }

    return 0;
}

char *str2lower (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;

    char *p = str;

    for (;*p;p++)
        if ('A' <= *p && *p <= 'Z')
            *p += 32;

    return str;
}
```

**output:**

```
$ ./bin/produce

Enter produce (quit to end): cherry
                  entry [ 1]  cherry     -> no match
  next: apple
                  entry [ 2]  apple      -> fruit
  next: lettuce
                  entry [ 3]  lettuce    -> vegetable
  next: banana
                  entry [ 4]  banana     -> fruit
  next: quit
```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be cheating to store some extra information along with the plant names?  Something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PLANT_COUNT 3

int main(int argc, char**argv)
{

    char line[10 + 1] = {'\0'};
    char *plants[PLANT_COUNT][10] = { {"apple", "fruit"}, {"orange", "fruit"}, {"cabbage", "vegetable"} };
    unsigned idx = 0;

    while (fgets(line, 10, stdin) != NULL)
    {

        /* Gets rid of the \n placed by fgets */
        strtok(line, "\n");

        for (idx = 0; idx < PLANT_COUNT; idx++)
        {
            if (strcmp(line, plants[idx][0]) == 0)
            {
                printf("Found %s.  It is a %s\n", line, plants[idx][1]);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```